# How to i write relationships to bellow three entity's?

Tags: angular, entity-framework, jhipster, jhipster-registry

If Suppose we have three entity's 
   entity UserProfile { firstname String
 lastname String 
}
 For the above entity primary key will generate automatically, same as we have another entity 
 entity SomeTest {
    unittest String
}
 entity Work{
    correction String
}

For the above entity's primary key will generate automatically, So now in user profile  entity we have two user records one is student and another one is teacher, in Some Test entity we have one test record that record have key ,so now how can i create relation to add user profile( student nd teacher primary keys)  and Some Test Primary key to Work entity.
Please can u write me the relationship to add userprofile & SomeTest Entity primary keys to Work Entity? ans like (relationship OneToMany{}) and what relation it will be and why?

Comment: Are you just talking about wanting to add a foreign key to an entity in EF?

Comment: difficult to understand what you are trying to do here. It's better if you can provide your use case in plain english. Accordingly we can help you to create your domain model

Comment: hi Narender Singh...

Comment: If we have 3 entity's one is take an example first entity is

Comment: If u have 3 entity's one is take an example first entity is                              entity UserProfile  {  firstname String, lastname String usertype Boolean }  (usertype either student or teacher)  and second one is   entity UnitTest  { test1 String }  and third one is... entity  WorkOrder { revision String }..now my question is how to create relationship in  jhipster to add  Userprofile id's(Both Teacher and student primary id's)  and UnitTest  id into WorkOrder.Do you know the jhipster management relationships.I need to create the relation like that.How u can create? do u understand?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @ChaitanyaChowdary Divi,

As per i understood, your flow is like this,

UserProfile( userid(pk) )
UnitTest( testid(pk) )
WorkOrder( userid(fk-One to Many), testid(fk-One to One) )

Right!!!

If it is right then you should follow this way,

Jhipster provide three way to generate relationship.

1. At the time of JDL file Creation.
2. At the time of Add New Entity using Terminal-command line.
3. Perform manually by editing existing entity class & chanagelog table.

Case 1 : Uni-Directional Relationship

```
relationship ManyToOne {
  WorkOrder{userid} to UserProfile
}
```

Note : If you use OneToMany(reverse order) it is compalsary to define field name of parent table.

```
relationship OneToOne {
  UnitTest{testid} to UserProfile{testid}
}
```

Case 2 : Add using Terminal - command line

```
yo jhipster:entity entityName
```

- Add the necessary fields
- At the end it ask about the relationship 
  Define name of the table name and appropriate column
- When it ask about the override option select "No"

Case 3 : Manually add in coding,

- Add Relationship in Entity file.

> @OneToOne(mappedBy = "UnitTest")
>
> @JsonIgnore
>
> private UnitTest unitTest;

- Make appropriate changes in DTO.
- Add column block in XML file.

  Resource -> config -> liquibase -> changelog -> entity.xml

  ```
  <changeSet id="add specialization column" author="jhipster">
          <addColumn tableName="specialization">
              <column name="specialization_id" type="bigint">
                  <constraints nullable="false"></constraints>
              </column>
          </addColumn>
      </changeSet>
  ```
- Apply this changes in JSON file also.

> /.jhipster/entity.json
>       {
>                   "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
>                   "relationshipName": "specialization",
>                   "otherEntityName": "specialization",
>                   "otherEntityField": "id"
>               },

- Perform Clean, Build, Run operation.
  This time it get the error of changelog,
      Copy the new changelog id
      Go to your database changelog table 
      perform update command and replace old id with new one.
- Perform Clean, Build, Run operation.